# Outline on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, display

I am trying to install Outline manager on a VPS. I installed ubuntu server mini 22.04 on it and I downloaded all the dependecies. When I tried to run it as an appimage file, as it is a GUI application on the ubuntu server I got such error.

```
root@b6e9e:~# sudo Applications/Outline-Manager.AppImage --no-sandbox
Outline Manager is starting
[66966:1018/111943.017901:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(248)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY 
[66966:1018/111943.017989:ERROR:env.cc(225)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting. Segmentation fault
```

I installed all these packages, libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 libnss3 libgbm-dev fuse

Also I failed to install xorg-x11-xaut with following command, I solved the issue on other server using this command but it is not working on this one:

```
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-xaut
```

And advice is apreciated.